# Скрипт, использующий поиск по реестру windows

Tags: windows, bat, скрипт, реестр

Приветствую! Передо мной стоит задача автоматизации удаления раздела в реестре по определенному условию.
В разделе `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` необходимо скриптом найти подраздел, содержащий в себе параметр (Имя: *"DisplayName"*, Значение: *"Example"*), и удалить этот подраздел.
Вся проблема в том, что подраздел каждый раз надо искать скриптом, ибо он имеет имя примерно такого вида: `{B99E3435-0B06-210C-B1B8-5954D5ADF936}`

Comment: Рискну предположить, что это имя может быть найдено в другом ключе реестра. Тогда задача сведется к получению имени, а не к поиску, что должно быть проще.

Comment: Это выглядит примерно так: http://joxi.ru/p2788qdcwjgJA7  
Так что, к сожалению, имя используется только в подразделе :(

Comment: Запустить `REG.EXE` и выгрузить указанную ветку в поток. Передать поток в `FIND.EXE`, оставить только строку с заданными значениями. Передать её в `FOR`, где распарсить на токены и получить имя раздела. Собрать команду удаления раздела и запустить `REG.EXE`, передав ему эту команду.